# infinite product expansion $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}-\frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have successfully solved that $$\frac{1}{\sin(z)}-\frac{1}{z} = \sum_{n=-\infty, n \neq 0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{z-n\pi}+\frac{1}{n\pi}\right)$$ and am now attempting to integrate both sides to get the infinite product expansion.  I successfully solved the LHS to yield $$\log{\frac{\tan{\frac{z}{2}}}{\frac{z}{2}}}$$ but am having a lot of trouble solving the RHS.  I know that the problem comes out to 
$$\frac{{\tan{\frac{z}{2}}}}{{\frac{z}{2}}} =\frac{\prod_{n=-\infty, n \neq 0}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z}{2n\pi}\right)e^{\frac{z}{2n\pi}}}{\prod_{n=-\infty}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z}{(2n+1)\pi}\right)e^{\frac{z}{(2n+1)\pi}}}$$ 
after I take the exponent of both sides to remove the log, but cannot figure out how to solve for this using the RHS above.

EDIT

The issue that I am having is going from $\sum_{n=-\infty, n \neq 0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{z-n\pi}+\frac{1}{n\pi}\right)$ to $\frac{\prod_{n=-\infty, n \neq 0}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z}{2n\pi}\right)e^{\frac{z}{2n\pi}}}{\prod_{n=-\infty}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z}{(2n+1)\pi}\right)e^{\frac{z}{(2n+1)\pi}}}$.  I can take $$\int_0^z \sum_{n=-\infty, n \neq 0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{z-n\pi}+\frac{1}{n\pi}\right) = \sum_{n=-\infty, n \neq 0}^\infty (-1)^n\left( \log\left(1-\frac{z}{n\pi}\right)+\frac{z}{\pi n}\right)$$ but that does not lead to the correct answer.

Comment: The last sum seems to be  the logarithm of the quotient of products above. Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe that is what I am missing.  I don't see how to get from that last sum to the products above.

Comment: Exponentiate the terms of the sum to get the terms of the product. The only thing being done is separating the even terms from the odd terms.

Comment: Does that not give $\prod_{n=-\infty, n \neq 0}^\infty (e^{(-1)^n})((1-\frac{z}{n\pi})e^{\frac{z}{n\pi}})$?  Again, I can't draw a connection between this and the solution.

Comment: No. $-\log(x)=\log(1/x)$, or equivalently, $e^{-x}=1/e^x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the exponentials for the positive $n$ and negative $n$ cancel each other out:
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{n=-N}^Ne^{\frac{\large z}{2n\pi}}=\lim_{N\to\infty}1=1
$$
and
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{n=-N}^Ne^{\frac{\large z}{(2n+1)\pi}}=\lim_{N\to\infty}e^{\frac{\large z}{(2N+1)\pi}}=1
$$
Thus, the product becomes
$$
\left.\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z^2}{4n^2\pi^2}\right)\middle/\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z^2}{(2n-1)^2\pi^2}\right)\right.
$$
Note that as mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function#Properties)
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z^2}{4n^2\pi^2}\right)=\frac{\sin(z/2)}{z/2}
$$
and using $2\cos(z/2)=\sin(z)/\sin(z/2)$, we get
$$
\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z^2}{(2n-1)^2\pi^2}\right)=\cos(z/2)
$$

Comment: Interesting, but I am trying to get from the RHS of the first equation (at the top of the question) to the statement at the bottom by taking the integral of the RHS.  This seems more like a simplification of the answer to me.

Comment: Okay, I am not seeing what you want shown. $\int_0^z\frac{(-1)^n}{w-n\pi}\,\mathrm{d}w =(-1)^n\log\left(1-\frac{z}{n\pi}\right)$. Adding these up gives the log of the product.

Comment: I have added a couple of product identities. Are those what you were looking for?

Comment: I can't use product identities, I have to directly solve using the integral and by taking the exponent of both sides.  I edited the problem, hopefully that will help you see how I am attempting to solve this.

Comment: You said that you already know how to show the infinite sum for $\frac1{\sin(z)}-\frac1z$. You have integrated the left side to get $\log\left(\frac{\tan(z/2)}{z/2}\right)$. You've integrated the sum on the right side to get the log of the product. What more are you trying to do?

Comment: I know what the answer is since it was given to me so that I would know if I had solved the problem correctly.  I do now know how to solve for it however.  I know the solution, but not the steps to solve for it myself.

Comment: which steps do you not know. You have given what looks to be complete above, but you have not shown which steps you do not understand.

Comment: How do I go from $ \sum_{n=-\infty, n \neq 0}^\infty (-1)^n\left( \log\left(1-\frac{z}{n\pi}\right)+\frac{z}{\pi n}\right)$ to $\frac{{\tan{\frac{z}{2}}}}{{\frac{z}{2}}} =\frac{\prod_{n=-\infty, n \neq 0}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z}{2n\pi}\right)e^{\frac{z}{2n\pi}}}{\prod_{n=-\infty}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z}{(2n+1)\pi}\right)e^{\frac{z}{(2n+1)\pi}}}$  What are the steps to do this?  I can take the exponent of both sides, as I have done in the comment at the top.  I don't see that those two terms are equivalent.  How do I get what I have into the exact form that I have been given?

Comment: Use the fact that $e^{-x}=1/e^x$ so that the odd terms appear in the denominator and the even terms in the numerator.

Comment: The separation of the even and odd terms is what I could not grasp.  I see now that that is why $(-1)^n$ goes away.  Thanks a bunch for your patience.

Comment: I'm glad we got that. This is an important idea for other products, so it is good to get this under your belt.